# Flex-wrap not working when placed onto parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a bio page and am looking to have a layout where 40% of the container will be placed in a fixed position on the left side of the screen. While having 60% of the main-content directly to the right of it where I can have it freely scroll when additional content is placed.

My problem is, before I start adding anything else onto my code, I was hoping to finish the layout first and have it be responsive. However, when I resize the window smaller, the flex-wrap doesn't work.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #252422;
  color: #fffcf2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-container {
  background-color: #eb5e28;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.content-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-container">

    <header class="left-container">
      <div>header</div>
    </header>

    <section class="content-container">
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>
      <h1>main</h1>

    </section>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Having a flex container with only two child elements of which one has `position: fixed` and the other `position: absoute`doesn't really make sense. (Nothing will wrap due to those position settings, flex doesn't apply at all due to those) Also, you should explain what doesn't work for you. In your snippet, it works as expected.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is when you resize the screen and it becomes smaller, its o make the header responsive and go above the main content when viewing on tablet or mobile. I know that I can accomplish this by media queries, but I was simply trying to use flex-wrap for something simple.